# Controller Extensions no Longer Working

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension

**Update**

I seem to also not be able to render a section based on the value of a user-input field in my form when the logic is called directly within my VF page.

Code from VF page

User-filled form field

```
     <p>  
        Client Population (Choose all that apply): <br></br> 
     </p>
     <div class="selectiondiv">
        <apex:inputField styleClass="fieldset" value="{!Intake__c.Population__c}">
             <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="seizures"/>
        </apex:inputField>
     </div>
```

Where it is called in the VF page

```
<apex:pageblock id="seizures">
      <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Intake__c.Population__c, 'Epilepsy/Seizures'), 'true', 'false')}" value="We do not currently support Epilepsy/Seizure-detecting technology."/> <br/>
      <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Intake__c.Population__c, 'Epilepsy/Seizures'), 'true', 'false')}" value="However, we may be able to assist with additionally noted concerns."/>
</apex:pageblock>
```

---

As of Friday, my visualforce page and Apex from controller extensions was working properly.  The extension renders a pageblocksection when certain logic is met.
As of today, pageblocksections are no longer rendering, and nothing has been changed with my code.
Has this happened to anyone before? Would there be a reason why it has just quit working?

Here are examples of my code.

VisualForce calling of the extensions.

```
<apex:page standardController="Intake__c" extensions="IntakeExtension,ShouldShowSHSection,ShouldShowSHwECSection,ShouldShowPERSSection,ShouldShowMedSection,ShouldShowRingSection" standardStyleSheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
```

VisualForce example of pageblocksection  render.

```
<apex:pageblockSection rendered="{!shouldShowMedSection}">
   <apex:outputText value="Medication Dispenser Recommendation"/>
</apex:pageblockSection>
```

Extension Example.

```
public with sharing class ShouldShowMedSection{
    public ShouldShowMedSection(ApexPages.StandardController paramController) {
       Intake = paramController;}
    public ApexPages.StandardController Intake {get; set;}
    public Boolean getShouldShowMedSection() {
       Intake__c record = (Intake__c)Intake.getRecord();
        
        
          if(
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Medication')
            ) 
            {
            return true;
            }
      
        
          return false;
        }
        
        }
```

Comment: Can you try redeploying all the extension classes again to rule out the possibility of one of the extensions failing?

Comment: @NagendraSingh - Yes - I have run another deployment, and it was successful

Comment: Did you also check for any overriding methods with same name?

Comment: @NagendraSingh - Yes - I have no overriding methods

Comment: @NagendraSingh - I seem to also not be able to render a section based on the value of a user-input field in my form when the logic is called directly within my VF page.  I'll update above.

Answer (score 0):

I had required="true" on a few user-input fields.  For some reason, this caused the rendering of sections based on the above logic to not render. Removing required="true" from all fields got the code working again.